# Do GL_TEXTUREs need to be released/freed?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a GLTexture class which initialises a texture from file with the following method:

```
void GLTexture::LoadBMP(char *name)
{
    // Create a place to store the texture
    AUX_RGBImageRec *TextureImage[1];

    // Set the pointer to NULL
    memset(TextureImage,0,sizeof(void *)*1);

    // Load the bitmap and assign our pointer to it
    TextureImage[0] = auxDIBImageLoad(name);

    // Just in case we want to use the width and height later
    width = TextureImage[0]->sizeX;
    height = TextureImage[0]->sizeY;

    // Generate the OpenGL texture id
    glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]);

    // Bind this texture to its id
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);

    // Use mipmapping filter
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

    // Generate the mipmaps
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, TextureImage[0]->sizeX, TextureImage[0]->sizeY, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, TextureImage[0]->data);

    // Cleanup
    if (TextureImage[0])
    {
        if (TextureImage[0]->data)
            free(TextureImage[0]->data);

        free(TextureImage[0]);
    }
}
```

Which does dispose of the data it seems. The texture is then used in the program by calling this function

```
void GLTexture::Use()
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);                                // Enable texture mapping
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);               // Bind the texture as the current one

}
```

Since the texture must somehow reside in memory for it to be able to be bound, I am wondering if any extra cleaning task is due upon exiting? Or whether the one in the loading method is sufficient....

Comment: This seems to be a good candidate for "read the documentation"

Comment: Please don't use the AUX library for loading images. Even if it works for you, it only encourages others to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you should use [`glDeleteTextures`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDeleteTextures.xml). You'll probably be able to get away without it on exit, as your whole context will be destroyed, but it's best practice to do it anyway.

Comment: Also, as Alf says above, read the documentation, this is even liked from the bottom of the page for `glGenTextures`!

Answer (score 2):

You should use

[glDeleteTextures](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDeleteTextures.xml)

Comment: @icecoder Thank you very much for your help! So if my GLTexture class has a `unsigned int texture[1];` that it uses for `glGenTexture` i should call a `glDeleteTextures(1, &texture)` for each instance of GLTexture or is there a way to delete them all at once?

Comment: You should call `glDeleteTextures` like this: `glDeleteTextures(`n`,&texture);` where `n` is numer of textures to delete. http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDeleteTextures.xml

Answer (score 1):

The `free` you see in your example code, is a call needed to free the data loaded from file.

When calling `gluBuild2DMipmaps`, OpenGL **copies** the data from the source you pass to it, but the OpenGL copy of your texture (the actual texture) still resides in memory (that's why you can use it after the `free` call).

When you finish using the textures, you should call [glDeleteTextures](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDeleteTextures.xml) in order to free the memory allocated by OpenGL.